# How to apply permissions per all tables?

Tags: hasura

My scenario is very simple. Two user roles one admin and one viewer. Viewer can see read-only data. Is it possible to somehow set this without manually specifying select permissions for every single table?
Seems like such a common problem but I can't find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no API method for changing permissions (or other metadata) across every table at once. It requires table name and schema.

I'm not sure what your "read-only" data permission translates into, but you can do this in two ways:

1. Call the metadata API with `create_select_permission` for every table name, programmatically

```
POST /v1/query HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Hasura-Role: admin

{
    "type" : "create_select_permission",
    "args" : {
        "table" : "article",
        "role" : "user",
        "permission" : {
            "columns" : "*",
            "filter" : {
                "author_id":{ "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id" }
             },
             "limit": 100,
             "allow_aggregations": false
        }
    }
}
```

2. Use the Metadata SDK to programmatically generate a `tables.yaml` or `metadata.json` which has the updated select permissions on every table, and then apply the metadata

See https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/5459

```js
import { Convert } from './customMetadataConverter'
import { TableEntry } from '../generated/HasuraMetadataV2'

// Read "tables.yaml" file as text from filesystem
const tablesMetadataFile = fs.readFileSync('./metadata/tables.yaml', 'utf8')
// Convert it to JSON object with type annotation using loadYAML utility
const tablesMetadata: TableEntry[] = Convert.loadYAML(tablesMetadataFile)

for (let table of tablesMetadata) {
  if (table.insert_permissions.length == 0) table.insert_permissions = []
  // Put the permission you want applied on every table here
  table.insert_permissions.push({
     columns : "*",
     filter : { user_id: { _eq: "X-Hasura-User-Id" } },
     limit: 100,
     allow_aggregations: false
  })
}
// Ouput the updated "tables.yaml" to filesystem
fs.writeFileSync('./tables-updated.yaml', Convert.metadataToYAML(tablesMetadata))
```

Comment: I used second approach.